# unable to update different row in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have create a sample which has differet layout for few rows in ListView based on the this [link](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296). Here is the layout

[image: Here is my layout]

As i want only first row to have a different layout , whenever the position is zero i am applying layout one ( Name & Phone) and for rest i am applying layout two (Address).

the problem i am facing is when i fire notifyDataSetChanged on adapter , only my Address get changed but Name & Phone row i.e. first row doesn't update. I am firing  notifyDataSetChanged when the submenu item is selected.

Here is the code.

```
public static final int TYPE_ADDRESS = 1;
public static final int TYPE_NAME = 0;
public static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT =2;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position == 0)
        return TYPE_NAME;
    else
        return TYPE_ADDRESS;
}
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder=null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);




 if (convertView == null) {
     holder = new ViewHolder();


    switch (type) {
        case TYPE_ADDRESS:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_address, null);
                    holder.address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address_id);                  
                    holder.address.setText(data.getAddress(position));


                    break;

        case TYPE_NAME:                        
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_name, null);                    
                    holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_id);
                    holder.phone = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone_id);



                    holder.name.setText(data.getName(position));
                    holder.phone.setText(data.getPhone(position));




                    break;
    }

        convertView.setTag(holder);          

   }else {

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }    



    return convertView;
}



static class ViewHolder {
        TextView address;
        TextView name;
        TextView phone;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you need to manage views (like setting text) outside `if (convertView == null){}else{}` block, since you need it to be invoked in any case, not only on view creating. Could it be the issue?

```
if (convertView == null) {
     holder = new ViewHolder();


    switch (type) {
        case TYPE_ADDRESS:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_address, null);
                    holder.address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address_id);                                     

                    break;

        case TYPE_NAME:                        
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_name, null);                    
                    holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_id);
                    holder.phone = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone_id);

                    break;
    }

        convertView.setTag(holder);          

   }else {

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }    

   switch (type) {
        case TYPE_ADDRESS:
              holder.address.setText(data.getAddress(position));
              break;
        case TYPE_NAME:                        
              holder.name.setText(data.getName(position));
              holder.phone.setText(data.getPhone(position)); 
              break;
```